# Is there a PDF/eBook Reader like the "Google Playbook"  Tablet?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader, google-play-books

I'm a really big fan of the Google Playbook reader, especially for an Android Tablet. I love the 2 columns and the effect when you go to other page. So I was wondering, is there a PDF/eBook reader with similar functionality as the Google Playbook? Unfortunately Google Playbooks don't allow to import documents in PDF or EPUB format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **You can import/upload them:**

### Uploading the PDF/ePub file(s) to your Library

1. Go to [My Books](https://play.google.com/books)
2. Click on 'Upload File' in the top right corner.
3. Choose the file(s) you wish to upload.

### Getting the PDF/ePub files in you App

1. Go into your [Google Play Books App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books&hl=en).
2. Click on the button on the top left ('Read Now' or 'My Library').
3. Select 'My Library'.
4. Click on the button just underneath it ('All books').
5. Click on 'Uploads'.
6. Click the Android Menu button.
7. Click on 'Refresh'
8. When you try to open the file, you may be prompted to download it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several apps you might check (ordered best recommendation first):

- [Moon+ Reader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp) is the best ebook reader I know. Support for the important formats (txt, html, epub, pdf, umd, fb2, chm, zip -- pdf only in the pro, said to be the fastest PDF renderer on Android), plenty libraries pre-configured to download books from (you can add your own sources), great support, and more. Just no DRM (yet; as Adobe didn't answer to the developers requests). My clear recommendation for this one.
- [Aldiko Book Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android) supports epub, PDF, DRM -- and also can access online sources
- [Mantano Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mantano.reader.android.lite) supports epub & PDF, available in several versions, supports DRM
- [GO Book](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gobook) supports epub, txt, umd, pdf and fb2 (DRM/catalogs support: unknown to me)

There are some more on the Playstore, but not all are recommendable (and some may have escaped my notice).

Comment: I tried all of those and found Mantano Reader to be the best.

Comment: After Izzy and @Fase comments i tried Mantano Reader and i love it aswell , it seems to support 2 columns but just in some PDFs, so i guess they have that option embedded?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has just updated their Kindle app to offer a two column layout for tablets. I was thrilled that they did this. Google Pay Book reader has that two page layout and I really preferred that on my tablet.

[Kindle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) app will also read PDF files. I don't think it will do EPUB but there might be a converter out there to make it into Kindle format.

There are several places to find good free Kindle books. I rarely pay for a book anymore.

Comment: it seems that this feature only works with native kindle books, i just tried with a PDF and can not shown as 2 column, but yo can with a kindle book